# The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a created a new policy for Azure B2C with custom Identity Provider.
But I see some error like this

"The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application"
I see the  reply url in the policy and the reply url of the Application for Identity provider has the same url.

What could be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your running code?

Comment: Can you please paste the actual (not expected) reply URL into the above question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try to set reply url/redirect url as : *https://**YOUR B2C TENANT NAME**.b2clogin.com/**YOUR B2C TENANT NAME**.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp* in your custom Identity Provider App.